# UITextView keyboard gets stuck

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uitextview

I am trying to dismiss keyboard and bring it back up programmatically, but after dismissal it gets stuck only the inputAccessoryView shows up. Can you please tell me what is going wrong? I have attached two images for the reference.
Thank You !

code

```
textView.resignFirstResponder()
            
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {
     self.textView.becomeFirstResponder()
}
```

before execution of the code

[image: before]

after execution of the code

[image: after]

Comment: Does it happen only on a simulator or on an actual iPhone as well?

Comment: It's happening on actual device. Happening on Both iPhone and iPad.

Answer (score 0):

The following fixed the issue:

- Delete all UITextView's
- Add new UITextView's

set the default lorem imposed text and change this programmatically in the `viewDidLoad()`

OR

Fully quit the simulator and rerun the app. If that doesn't work, try with new simulator or device.